# Use EditorFor to output fields for derived type of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
```

I've got a template for an `A` which gets used like so...

```
EditorFor(m => m.MyA)
```

An `A` can also be a `B` so within my template for an `A` I want to output the extra `B` fields if the item being bound is a `B`.

So in my `A` template:

```
@{
  Html.EditorFor(i => i as B);
}
```

Gives...

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions.

I tried using the following which outputs the fields except the form element names don't have the prefix on them of the parent element.

```
@{
  Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/B.cshtml", Model as B, new ViewDataDictionary());
}
```

Comment: What happens if you write something like @{ var b = Model as B; @Html.EditorFor(i => b); } ?

Comment: I did a quick test. No error but nothing was output. If you see my answer I got this working with RenderPartial and manually adding the missing prefix data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works...

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/B.cshtml", Model as B, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData)
{
    Model = Model as B
});
```

Comment: This actually works as well: `@Html.Partial("B", Model)`. What I can't figure out is why the `EditorForModel("B")` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There is another solution if you would still like to do the Editor Template route.  You create templates for each of the types, showing only the fields for that type.  You then create a helper that calls `EditorFor` passing it a template name of the name of the base type and add that to a call to `EditorFor` for this type.

Models:

```
public class ModelA
{
    public string PropA { get; set; }
}

public class ModelB : ModelA
{
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}
```

Template for *ModelA*:

```
@model MvcTest.Models.ModelA
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PropA)
```

Template for *ModelB*:

```
@model MvcTest.Models.ModelB
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.PropB)
```

Helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorForDerived<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper
    , Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var baseHtml = helper.EditorFor(expression, helper.ViewData.Model.GetType().BaseType.Name);
    var derivedHtml = helper.EditorFor(expression);
    return new MvcHtmlString(baseHtml.ToHtmlString() + derivedHtml.ToHtmlString());
}
```

View:

```
@model MvcTest.Models.ModelB
@Html.EditorForDerived(m => m)
```

Produces this output:

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="PropA" name="PropA" type="text" value="valA" />
<input class="text-box single-line" id="PropB" name="PropB" type="text" value="valB" />
```

Comment: Aha... the problem with this is that I need my extra fields inserted amongst the the base class fields on the UI. Perhaps this suggests that my class design is incorrect.